# Is there a way to set dynamic top position to an element depend on another element?

Tags: html, css

I have a sidebar in my website with flex display. It has second parts the first one has dynamic height and sticky position because of the accordions(li tags) inside it when the accordions close the height is 432px but when they extend the height change to 552px. The second one must be have sticky but the top position depend on the first part. I am searching for the way to put dynamic top position.
the sudoku sth like this:

```
   <div class="sidebar flex flex-direction:column">
     <ul class="firstpart position:sticky top:70px">
       <li class="accordion">filters</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="secondpart position:sticky top:?">
      <img src="sth"/>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clearer. We need a more detailed explanation of the exact visual effect you are after. Create some annotated drawings or mockups of various configurations and include those in your question.